# HTML/JS: <a> not correct after array shuffle

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, hyperlink, shuffle

using HTML and JavaScript (in a NextJS environment) I have the following problem:

I have an **array with objects** like that:

```
const personArray =
[
  {name: "person1", age: "22", link:"www.person1.de"},
  {name: "person2", age: "35", link:"www.person2.de"},
  {name: "person3", age: "18", link:"www.person3.de"},
]
```

Before I render these elements in my HTML by iterating with .map(), I want to **shuffle** the elements by using this function:

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }

const newPersonArray = shuffleArray(personArray)
```

This works fine so far, the **elements are shuffled correctly** and when I display the elements as described below, it works. **The only exception is the link**.

```
{newPersonArray.map((person) => {
  return (
   <>
    <h1>{person.name}</h1>
    <p>{person.age}</p>
    <a href={person.link}>Link</a>
   </>
  )
})}
```

The link is always wrong, e.g. person 1 has link from person 2. What is interesting here is that the **order of the links is also mixed**, so not in their original order.... but also not in the same order as all other elements. **When I log the array in the console, everything is mapped correctly**.... Even if I display the link like this:

```
<a href={person.link}>{person.link}</a>
```

The visual representation of the link is correctly assigned (person1.de is at person 1) - but **when you click on the link, it is the wrong one**. Thus, I assume that the `<a>` tag is the problem. But where exactly is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the wrong url? Everything looks fine to me :)

```js
const personArray =
[
  {name: "person1", age: "22", link:"http://www.person1.de"},
  {name: "person2", age: "35", link:"http://www.person2.de"},
  {name: "person3", age: "18", link:"http://www.person3.de"},
]

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }

const newPersonArray = shuffleArray(personArray)

let result = newPersonArray.map((person) => {
  return (
     `<div><h1>${person.name}</h1><p>${person.age}</p><a href="${person.link}">Link</a></div>`
  )
})


document.querySelector(".result").insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', result );
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: In your code snippet everything works fine ... in my project, unfortunately, it does not. You can check it here: "https://chargeiq.de" 
When you scroll the page down to the team member, you can see, that the LinkedIn profiles are not correctly linked. And I used exactly that code you posted...